# Node.js and Mongoose, too slow to put Schema definitions in separate files?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Playing around with Node.js and I really want to keep my file structure organized.  Normally in a project in another language I would have a structure like this:

- Node App Directory

  - App.js
  - Controllers

    - UserController.js
    - OtherController.js
  - Models

    - UserModel.js
    - OtherModel.js

The (potential) problem I see is this:  I use Mongoose and MongoDB for my database, in order to define a "Model" I need a Mongoose Schema, in order to do that I have to connect to the database with Mongoose in each of the Controllers and Model files.

I know so little about these technologies, this could be lightning quick and never be an issue and I wouldn't have a clue.  Or is this something I should avoid and just shove everything in one (very large) file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  don't need to connect to mongo in every controller/model file. Just do it once in `App.js` and you're done.

Comment: Seriously?  So I can just say `mongoose.Schema` in any "required" files without declaring the mongoose variable?

Comment: You are getting confused.  Yes you need to do `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` in each file but that does NOT connect to the DB.  Only an explicit call to `mongoose.connect(url)` will actually do IO to the database.  Also, mongoose operations are queued until a connection is made, so you can do mongoose setup stuff before (or after) you connect without worry.